# Is the HDD spinning when it is unmounted?

Tags: hard-drive, power-management, spindown

Have a PC with multiple HDDs some used only for backup. Should I leave them unmounted? IS the power consumption less when the HDD is unmounted? Do the HDDs spin when unmounted?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Most modern HDDs will spin down after sometime of inactivity, regardless of them being mounted or unmounted. Reducing that time will reduce power consumption, but mounting in this case seems to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The HDDs will still spin if unmounted.  I've got 2 HDDs  sitting right besides me unmounted and they can clearly be heard spinning.